# Error de permisos en la conexion mysql centos 7.0.1406

Tags: php, mysql, centos7

1. Error muestra que pagina no funciona. error 505.
   [image]

Se soluciona ingresando lo siguiente en el codigo php para mostrar el error. tambien se puede configurar en php.ini en la configuracion del php.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

2. Error Permisos denegados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se soluciona ingresando lo siguiente en el servidor

```
[root @ localhost] # setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
[root @ localhost] # setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

3. error no conecta directamente con la ip 192.168.x.x, pero si conecta con "localhost"
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La librería mysql es obsoleta y desapareció a partir de PHP v7, cambia a mysqli o, mejor aún, a PDO; en cualquiera de los dos casos usa sentencias preparadas: php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: verdad, me olvide comentar que la versión que estoy usando PHP 5.4.16.